# Associative array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am doing a back-end validation and I wonder if there is a better way to do this instead of typing all the variables of each data, here's my code

```
  public function status_check()       
    {
        $radioStatus = $this->input->post('radioStatus');

        $JuniorHS = array(    
            $SeniorHSGradeYear = $this->input->post('SeniorHSGradeYear'),
            $radioHSTracks = $this->input->post('radioHSTracks'),
            $radioCollegeCourses = $this->input->post('radioCollegeCourses'),
            $radioGraduateCourses = $this->input->post('$radioGraduateCourses'),
            $hsSchoolName = $this->input->post('$hsSchoolName'),
            $hsSchoolLocation = $this->input->post('$hsSchoolLocation'),
            $hsYearsAttended = $this->input->post('$hsYearsAttended'),
            $hsGradDate = $this->input->post('$hsGradDate'),
            $collegeSchoolName = $this->input->post('$collegeSchoolName'),
            $collegeSchoolLocation = $this->input->post('$collegeSchoolLocation'),
            $collegeYearsAttended = $this->input->post('$collegeYearsAttended'),
            $formerCollegeDegree = $this->input->post('$formerCollegeDegree'),
            $collegeGradDate = $this->input->post('$collegeGradDate'),
        );

        if  ($radioStatus == "JuniorHS")
        {
            if (!empty($JuniorHS))
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('status_check', 'Please check the information you provided');
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I put all the variables inside an array then i want to check if any of it has a value, if the array is not empty then it will return as false, hence if its empty then it will return true, but the code always return as false even if its empty, am i even doing it right?

Comment: what returns ````if  ($radioStatus == "JuniorHS")````??

Comment: `$JuniorHS` will never be empty. You're filling it with 13 things. Some of those individual things may or may not be empty, but an empty array in PHP means it contains 0 values.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what the code is supposed to do? Are you just trying to make sure none of those form fields are empty?

Comment: This is going to depend on just how *specific* you want to be with the validation and what kind of fields are in there - I mean, if you've got a field for Teletubbies you **only** want to allow `['Dipsy', 'La La', 'Po', 'Tinky-Winky']` and not **Nyarlathotep, the Creeping Chaos** - which means a simple `!empty()` validation isn't going to cut it; it's still going to allow a Cyclopean Horror to invade Teletubbyland!

Comment: I think i did it wrong, anyway I've corrected it now, I changed $SeniorHSGradeYear = $this->input->post('SeniorHSGradeYear'), to "SeniorHSGradeYear" => $this->input->post('SeniorHSGradeYear')., I just want to know now if its possible to check the array for empty values without doing a for loop

Comment: @Don't Panic, Yes, all of those form fields inside that array should be empty to return as true.

Comment: @CD001 Hmm.. if !empty() is not good then what should i put in my validation to avoid those Cyclopean Horror to invade my Teletubbyland?

Comment: @AlexisGarcia, if $radioStatus == "JuniorHS" then it will check the $JuniorHS array if its completely empty, if its not then it will return the validation as false.

Comment: Dude i know that lol, im asking what it gives to you. It pass's the if? you get a true there? have you check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was reading that:

Since CI 2.1.0, you can now do the following easy way to get all post data from the form.

```
$data = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); // returns all POST items with XSS filter
$data = $this->input->post(); // returns all POST items without XSS filter
```

So, I think this could work for you:

```
public function status_check()       
    {
        $data = $this->input->post();

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == 'radioStatus') {
                $radioStatus = $value;
            }else{
                $JuniorHS[] = $value;
            }
        }

        if  ($radioStatus == "JuniorHS")
        {
            foreach ($JuniorHS as $key => $value) {
                if (!empty($value))
                {
                    $this->form_validation->set_message('status_check', 'Please check the information you provided');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used CodeIgniter, but looking at their documentation you should be able to:

`$data = $this->input->post();`

This will give you an array containing all POST items, that you can pass into your validator. So if you do not specify which items you want in the post method, then you get all of them. The same goes for GET.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround for a generic validation (required+trim) would be to put each input validation rule inside a loop :

```php
        foreach($_POST as $p) {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules($p, ucfirst($p), 'required|trim');
        } 

        if  ($radioStatus == "JuniorHS")
        {
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('status_check', 'Please check the information you provided');
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys for the response. Here's my updated code.

```
public function status_check()       
    {
        $radioStatus = $this->input->post('radioStatus');

        $data = $this->input->post();

        $JuniorHSinfo = array(    
            "SeniorHSGradeYear" => $this->input->post('SeniorHSGradeYear'),
            "radioHSTracks" => $this->input->post('radioHSTracks'),
            "radioCollegeCourses" => $this->input->post('radioCollegeCourses'),
            "radioGraduateCourses" => $this->input->post('$radioGraduateCourses'),
            "hsSchoolName" => $this->input->post('$hsSchoolName'),
            "hsSchoolLocation" => $this->input->post('$hsSchoolLocation'),
            "hsYearsAttended" => $this->input->post('$hsYearsAttended'),
            "hsGradDate" => $this->input->post('$hsGradDate'),
            "collegeSchoolName" => $this->input->post('$collegeSchoolName'),
            "collegeSchoolLocation" => $this->input->post('$collegeSchoolLocation'),
            "collegeYearsAttended" => $this->input->post('$collegeYearsAttended'),
            "formerCollegeDegree" => $this->input->post('$formerCollegeDegree'),
            "collegeGradDate" => $this->input->post('$collegeGradDate'),
        );

        $result = array_intersect_key($data, $JuniorHSinfo);

        if  ($radioStatus == "JuniorHS") 
            {
                foreach ($result as $key => $value)
                {
                        if (!empty($value)) 
                        {
                            $this->form_validation->set_message('status_check', 'Please check the information you provided');
                            return false;
                        }
                }
            }
        return true;
    }
```